# Apache standard output stream

Tags: c++, linux, apache

In my cpp file I am printing some debug messages to std::cout standard output stream. When i use this file and run the executable using Apache server. Where will the debug messages get printed. I don't see them printed in /var/lib/httpd/error_log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "run the executable using Apache server", you run the executable as a CGI program?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Cgicc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/) library for such a project. Also, as a quick test, you can try to write messages from your C++ code to a file (which has the required permissions), just to see that it's actually being executed.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I tried outputting to a file. It works that way. I am using my Cpp executable form a script, that runs in Apache.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason you should be using the Apache web server to run a C++ program is if your making a CGI script

Check it out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

---

The process here is that Apache, the web server, runs your program and uses the output(std::cout) as the page source.

The page source can either be html or plain text. The only problem is the server doesn't know, so you provide it with a little hint at the start of your output. It's called the header.

If your outputting html you must print:

> Content-type: text/html

followed by *two* newlines.

or if you want the web server to interpret the data as plain text, you must initially print

> Content-type: text/plain

also followed by *two* newlines.

---

For example, a C++ program which should work would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  //output header, then one newline, then another, paired with a flush.
  std::cout << "Content-type: text/plain\n" << std::endl;
  //now your output
  //calculation...
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Any web server parameters can be queried with some pre-set environment variables. Read up on the wikipedia article I linked.

---

**EDIT:**

I apologize, The `Content-type: text/html` and `Content-type: text/plain` was correct, but I previously said they required a new line. I was mistaken, they require two new lines

If this is the first time you are seeing this post, than don't worry about it.

Comment: I would guess the standard output could either be accessible from perl when you run the program, or very possibly perl or the apache web server redirects the output to /dev/null or something. I would say edit the question to state that you are using perl, from your question I thought you were having trouble with c++ in general. The problem here is your perl code, not the server, and not the executable.